# How to get a normalized value to change a UI text element in Unity?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I have a normalized value coming from the current position of an animation. How do I convert this to a text output depending on the value within the `string`?

for example

```
if (animation.Time < 0.1)
{
    text = January;
}

else (0.1 < animation.Time < 0.2)
{
    text = February;
}
```

etc, all the way until 1, because of normalized value.

I realise this code won't work at all, but I think this is the logic needed to get it to work, but so far I've had no luck.

edit, Elaborated question. I have a slider that moves depending on the progression of an animation, it does this via converting the animationTime to a normalized value so that slider fills up in relation to the animation.

I'd like to take the value of this normalized time to display the current related date of the animation, on screen, so if the animation shows a years progression, as the slider moves up and so does the normalized value I can have some text that will count up in months.

I hope this makes more sense now.

Comment: Can you elaborate "How do I convert this to a text output depending on the value within the string?"?

Comment: I've given some more info on the question, hopefully this helps illustrate what I'm after.

Comment: So your question is actually how you would go about to implement your pseudo code?

Comment: Hi Tim, you see the DIVISION POINTS for the number.  So, you give the examples of .1, .2, .3 and so on.  Are they ALL EVENLY SPACED, or are they just "random points" (like, you know they are, for example, .15, .18, .22, .23, .30, etc).

Comment: They would be evenly spaced, the animation is set to 1 frame is 1 day therefore the output of the animation is linear to the time passed. So say the animation shows 10 months the division to switch from one month to another would be 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## To get a "month string" in Unity just do this...

say you have "3" ..

```
string monthString = new System.DateTime(1,3,1).ToString("MMMM");
Debug.Log("Teste " + monthString );
```

Result, "March".

So make yourself a function

```
private string MonthFromInt(int m)
 {
 string monthString = new System.DateTime(1, m ,1).ToString("MMMM");
 return monthString;
 }
```

and then use that.

---

Regarding the control structure you need.  You mention it is "between two values". To do that you just

```
if ( 0.00f < t && t <= 0.23f ) do something here...
```

I suggest to KISS just do the following. Just fill in the values:

```
float t = animation.time (or whatever)
string text = "?";

if ( 0.00f <= t && t <= 0.23f ) text = MonthFromInt(0);
if ( 0.23f < t && t <= 0.41f ) text = MonthFromInt(1);
if ( 0.41f < t && t <= 0.66f ) text = MonthFromInt(2);
if ( 0.66f < t && t <= 0.68f ) text = MonthFromInt(3);
... etc ...
if ( 0.91f < t && t <= 1.00f ) text = MonthFromInt(11);
```

Use the "<" and then "<=" just as above. hope it helps!

Comment: I'll have to use the `monthAsInt` seeing as the float is the normalizedTime value from the animator. I'll give it a go and see where I end up.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the code for this, and I just don't know where to start, I don't understand why I can't just say if the animatorTime.normalizedTime is between two specified values then the text outputs a certain string.

Comment: Do I need to make this as a new script, or put it in the one where I'm getting the normalized value from? In this case the animation.time?

Comment: i think it's fine to put it in the same script.  you understand about the function `MonthFromInt` right?  put that also in the same script.  In your `Awake` do this to test it ... `Debug.Log("test! " + MonthFromInt(7));`  try a couple different values (7, 3, 0 etc) , in each case press Play and watch the console.  So, first test your `MonthFromInt` routine!

Comment: I get it, I was fumbling around with stuff and now it makes sense. Many thanks again.

Comment: my pleasure, it's a great example for googlers of where you use `System.DateTime` ... it's quite annoying, one is using things like that all the time in Unity projects .. to bring up strings etc.